# Windows Defender API to scan a directory for malwares

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-defender

Using [Windows Defender API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn920144(v=vs.85).aspx) , I'm trying to do a scan for malwares on a folder. 
Following [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn920120(v=vs.85).aspx) I wrote the code:

```
MPRESOURCE_INFO ResourceInfo = { 0 };
MPSCAN_RESOURCES ScanResource = { 0 };
PMPRESOURCE_INFO ResourceInfoArray = NULL;
...
ResourceInfo.Scheme = L"dir";
ResourceInfo.Path = L"C:\\temp";
ResourceInfo.Class = 0;

// ResourceInfoArray was Allocated before
*ResourceInfoArray = ResourceInfo;
ScanResource.dwResourceCount = 1;
ScanResource.pResourceList = ResourceInfoArray;

// Opened hMpManager before using MpScanStart
hRetval = MpScanStart(hMpManager, MPSCAN_TYPE_RESOURCE, 0, &ScanResource, NULL, &ScanHnadle);
```

From which I get an error message: `An unexpected problem occurred. Install any available updates, and then try to start the program again. For information on installing updates, see Help and Support.`

However If I change the ResourceInfo definition to:

```
ResourceInfo.Scheme = L"file";
ResourceInfo.Path = L"C:\\temp\\MyFile.exe";
ResourceInfo.Class = 0;
```

It works great, detecting the file in the right way.
On the bottom line - the code works for files, but doesn't work for directories.
Does anyone know what am I doing wrong with the directory search?

Comment: I would guess it doesn't scan directories, only files, and that you'll need to traverse the directory tree yourself.

Comment: It says ["file" or "dir"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn920120(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Try "C:\\Temp\\"

Comment: Tried this one before, it doesn't work either

Comment: @KonstantinL: `C:\\Temp\\​​` does not name a directory. `C:\\Temp` does.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing event logs created by MpCmdRun.exe I found out that it uses the scheme "folder" instead of "dir". That change made my code working.

```
ResourceInfo.Scheme = L"folder";
```

Folder paths do not have to end with backslash, but drives require it: (F:\).